# how to insert data php javascript mysql with multiple array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to enter data in multiple arrays into a database with php javascript 
here i use dynamic add record to insert value

This is an example :

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="form-produk">
<input name='add_btn' class="btn btn-primary" value='Tambah Record' id='add_btn' type='button'><br><br>

                 <div id='container1'></div>


</form>

         <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
            var count = 0;

            $("#add_btn").click(function(){
                    count ++;
                $('#container1').append(
                             '<div class="records">'
                         + '<textarea id="' + count + '" name="' + count + '" type="text" size="100" class="form-control nma_prod"></textarea>'
            + '<div class="hrgini"><span class="input-group-addon">Rp</span><input style="text-align:right" id="' + count + '" name="'+count+'" class="form-control hrg_prod" type="text" placeholder="Harga Produk"><span class="input-group-addon">,00</span></div>'
                         + '<button class="remove_item btn btn-danger" >Hapus</button>'
                         + '<br><br></div>'
                    );
                });

                $(".remove_item").live('click', function (ev) {
                if (ev.type == 'click') {
                $(this).parents(".records").fadeOut();
                $(this).parents(".records").remove();
            }
            });
        });
</script>
```

and this is my action with javascript

```
$("#simpan-produk").bind("click", function(event) {
            var url = "pages/produk/produk.input.php";

            // mengambil nilai dari inputbox, textbox dan select
            var values = new Object() // creates a new instance of an object
                    $('.nma_prod').each(function() {
                        values[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
                })
            var harga = new Object() // creates a new instance of an object
                    $('.hrg_prod').each(function() {
                        values[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
                })

            // send to process
            $.post(url, {nama: values,hrga: harga, id: id_produk} ,function() {
                $(".msg").html("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable' id='alerts'> Sucsess</div>");
                    $(".msg").fadeIn(3500);
                    $(".msg").show();
                    $(".msg").fadeOut(5500);
                $("#data-produk").load(main);


                // hide dialog modals
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');

                // restore modal dialog title
                $("#myModalLabel").html("Tambah Data produk");
            });
        });
```

and this is my proces script

```
foreach($prods as $_POST['nama']){
                foreach($hrg as $_POST['hrga']){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO produk VALUES('','$prods','$hrg')");
            }
        }
```

but This script didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: what error you got ?

Comment: value from dynamic record can't added to database

Comment: in values why you put first value as ' ' (as blank) ?

Comment: this is id i i declare to '' (blank) because i use primary key in table

Comment: You are doing `Insert` operation, why do you need `PRIMARY KEY`, PK is never created using JS counter..

Comment: Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/own1aw8p/

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: if you set auto increment primary key into database than just use query like this INSERT INTO produk(prods_column_name,hrg_column_name) VALUES('$prods','$hrg')

Answer (score 0):

when you use integer for `name` attribute, you have problem in server side script.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nby8jj5k/1/)

you must do like this :

```
            $('#container1').append(
                         '<div class="records">'
                     + '<textarea id="id_' + count + '" name="count[]" type="text" size="100" class="form-control nma_prod"></textarea>'
        + '<div class="hrgini"><span class="input-group-addon">Rp</span><input style="text-align:right" id="cnt_' + count + '" name="count2[]" class="form-control hrg_prod" type="text" placeholder="Harga Produk"><span class="input-group-addon">,00</span></div>'
                     + '<button class="remove_item btn btn-danger" >Hapus</button>'
                     + '<br><br></div>'
                );
            });
```

then in ajax send you can use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) :

```
      // send to process
        $.post(url, $('form#form-produk').serialize(),function() {
                 // ....
        });
```

finally :

```
$v = [];
    foreach($_POST['count'] as $key=>$count){

        $v[] = "('',$count,{$_POST['count2'][$key]})";

    }

$query = "INSERT INTO produk ".implode(',',$v);
```

I don't know your fields name. `count` and `count2` just a temp name. please change these.

and never use mysql_* functions

Comment: OP is not submitting for in conventional way, He is using ajax.. Why do he need names ? he is not using `serialize()` either...

Comment: yes your right about `name`, but `serialize()` needed to collect and send form data.

Comment: but how to declare post data in serialize() with dynamic record ?

Comment: actually we need `name` when we want to use `serialize()`

Comment: @AvistaKautsar : please check this code and see the result.

Comment: i have 

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO produk VALUES('','$kat','$count','$_POST[count2][$key]')");

Answer (score 0):

In provided example, why are you creating different objects for two different fields ?

As both the fields are related(In a group), you need to have them in same object. SO the key here is `iterate` through all the elements having class `records`

> `bind` and `live` are deprecated so I am using `on` over that.
>
> On `php` side, It is better to *concatenate* the `queries` and execute them once rather than executing multiple queries.

`JSON` is being send as a `data` and `json_decode` method is used to get the `object` out of `string`

`mysqli_*` methods should be used instead of `mysql_*` as mentioned in the *comments* but in the code provided below, it is not implemented.

Refer this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;

  $("#add_btn").click(function() {
    count++;
    $('#container1').append(
      '<div class="records">' + '<textarea id="' + count + '" name="' + count + '" type="text" size="100" class="form-control nma_prod"></textarea>' + '<div class="hrgini"><span class="input-group-addon">Rp</span><input style="text-align:right" id="' + count + '" name="' + count + '" class="form-control hrg_prod" type="text" placeholder="Harga Produk"><span class="input-group-addon">,00</span></div>' + '<button class="remove_item btn btn-danger" >Hapus</button>' + '<br><br></div>'
    );
  });

  $('body').on('click', ".remove_item", function(ev) {
    $(this).parents(".records").fadeOut();
    $(this).parents(".records").remove();
  });
});

$("#simpan-produk").on("click", function(event) {
  var url = "pages/produk/produk.input.php";
  var data = [];
  $('.records').each(function(index, item) {
    var nma_prod = $(item).find('.nma_prod').val();
    var hrg_prod = $(item).find('.hrg_prod').val();
    data.push({
      nma_prod: nma_prod,
      hrg_prod: hrg_prod
    });
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  // send to process
  $.post(url, {
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  }, function() {
    $(".msg").html("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable' id='alerts'> Sucsess</div>");
    $(".msg").fadeIn(3500);
    $(".msg").show();
    $(".msg").fadeOut(5500);
    $("#data-produk").load(main);
    // hide dialog modals
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');

    // restore modal dialog title
    $("#myModalLabel").html("Tambah Data produk");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form-produk">
  <input name='add_btn' class="btn btn-primary" value='Tambah Record' id='add_btn' type='button'>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id='container1'></div>

  <button id='simpan-produk' type='button'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$query = '';
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $nma_prod = $item['nma_prod'];
    $hrg_prod = $item['hrg_prod'];
    $query .= "INSERT INTO `produk` VALUES('$nma_prod','$hrg_prod');";
}

if ($query) {
    $exec = mysql_query($query);
    if ($exec) {
        echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Data inserted successfully!'));
        exit;
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Something went wrong!'));
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Nothing to Insert!'));
    exit;
}
```

Refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/own1aw8p/1/) for client-side code..

Comment: but why if i insert with more one data its not works ?

Comment: _Does not work_ is not a valid problem statement. There are simple debugging steps you need to follow. Check the `$query` being generated in `loop`. Is it valid ?